# Kindle Fire Game Circle CANNOT_BIND error

Tags: android, kindle-fire

Has anyone tried implementing Amazon's GameCircle into their Kindle Fire app?

I can't get it pass the initialization stage:

```
EnumSet<AmazonGamesFeature> myGameFeatures = EnumSet.of(AmazonGamesFeature.Leaderboards);
```

onCreate:

```
AmazonGamesClient.initialize(getApplication(), new AmazonGamesCallback() 
{ 
@Override 
public void onServiceReady() 
{ 
} 

@Override 
public void onServiceNotReady(AmazonGamesStatus reason) 
{ 
switch (reason)
{ 
   case CANNOT_BIND: 
      Log.d(Globals.sApplicationName, "onCreate: CANNOT_BIND");
      break;
   case CANNOT_AUTHORIZE: 
      Log.d(Globals.sApplicationName, "onCreate: CANNOT_AUTHORIZE");
      break;
   case NOT_AUTHORIZED: 
      Log.d(Globals.sApplicationName, "onCreate: NOT_AUTHORIZED");
      break;
   case NOT_AUTHENTICATED: 
      Log.d(Globals.sApplicationName, "onCreate: NOT_AUTHENTICATED");
      break;
} 

} 

}, myGameFeatures);
```

I get these errors when running the game:

```
07-31 15:45:39.609: E/AGC_ServiceProxy(970): Amazon Games Service is not available
07-31 15:45:39.609: D/AGC_ServiceProxy(970): Changing Status from:INITIALIZING to: CANNOT_BIND
07-31 15:45:39.619: E/GC_AmazonGamesClient(970): Failed to enable softkey button: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.amazon.ags.app
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "whitelist" your binary.  Go into the Amazon App store developer console and into the unpublished version of the game itself, then the "GameCircle" section and click on "Whitelist Registery".  Then click on the "Whitelist a Binary" button.

Enter the package name of your game, and to get the key hash run this command from a Command Prompt (for Windows):

```
keytool -exportcert -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

That should give you a short base 64 hash of the key you use to sign the debug build of your game.  You will have to do something similar for a release build, since it's signed with a different key.

**EDIT**

In addition to the above, also make certain your Kindle Fire is registered to an actual Amazon account and that it has at least version 6.3.1 of the system software.  We had a Fire that was not registered and thus never got the software upgrade that contained GameCircle.  I also believe GameCircle requires you to be signed into an Amazon account to work.

Answer (score 2):

Did not work on Emulator for me. Worked like charm on the Kindle Fire device.

Comment: Amazon's tech replied and said that it shouldn't work on the emulator, the emulator is not supported for GameCircle.

Comment: I am currently using the emulator and am using GameCircle within it.  Maybe they added support for it since the previous comment.